# Converting int to char in c#. But after converting the value, char holds nothing

Tags: c#, type-conversion, char, integer, gettype

```cs
char chr1 = '9';
int num = 9;
char chr2 = (char)num;
if(chr1 == chr2)
   Console.WriteLine("It worked");
else 
   Console.WriteLine("It did not work");
Console.WriteLine(chr2.GetType().Name);
Console.Write(chr2);
```

I want to convert an int to a char and compare it with another char. When i ran this code the output is

```
It did not work
Char
```

So it converts int to a char successfully but `chr2` has no value it prints nothing (but its move the cursor)
Hence it has no value if is not working but i didn't understand why `chr2` has no value.

Comment: If you'd expect `(char)9` to give you the character `9`, what integer would you need to start with to get the character 'A'?

Comment: `Hence it has no value if is not working` - have you considered that it may have a *different* value, and then it would also not work?

Comment: You have a debugger. Stop the program and look at the value of `chr` then look at Unicode code point 0x09 (or just look at an ASCII table)

Comment: `(char)9` is gonna give you a **Tab**, because that's how the characters are encoded.

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
char chr2 = Convert.ToChar(num.ToString());
```

or thanks to @Charlieface

```
char chr2 =  num.ToString()[0];
```

this is because

```
num=Convert.ToByte(9); //9   it is invisible ASCII code - horisontal tab
num=Convert.ToByte('9') //57  it is visible ASCII code '9'
```

Comment: Or `num.ToString()[0]`

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, you are right, I just wanted to show that number 9 and string "9" are very different.